# encoding error when trying to run pyinstaller executable as service in linux

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I used pyinstaller 3.5 to create an executable from a python script. to compile i used:

pyinstaller -F --onefile --add-data :. my_script.py

I'm trying to run this executable as systemd service. The service file is:

```
   ***[Unit]

   Description= a description

   [Service]

   Type=simple

   Restart=on-failure

   User=root

   RestartSec=3

   ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 path/to/my_script

   [Install]

   WantedBy=multi-user.target***
```

When i start the service via systemctl start service i get the following error:

```
   :SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xe8' in file /path/to/my_script on line 2, but no 
    encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

and the service is exiting with status=1/FAILURE

When i'm running the service my_script.py everything works great.

I don't use in my code non utf-8 characters.

I tried to add encoding defenition of all sorts. for example:

```
***\# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-***
```

I tried commenting almost every line in the code to find the source but i kept getting the error.
I saw a similar problem here [Error when using pyinstaller: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692960/error-when-using-pyinstaller-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byt) but the fix they suggested didn't work for me

Anyone knows how to solve it?

I'm working with python 3.6.9

Linux red hat 7.5

Comment: use `utf-8` instead `latin-1` or better don't use any native chars - even in comments.

Comment: it shows problem with `'\xe8'` which in `latin-1` gives `è` -`print( b'\xe8'.decode('latin-1') )` - find it and remove it from file.

Comment: i tried utf-8 as well

Comment: no è is present in my python script

Comment: but Python see some  `è` in second line of your script. Maybe delete second line and write it again.

Comment: if `mycript` is the output of `Pyinstaller`, then you shouldn't try to execute it with `Python`. Just use: `ExecStart=/path/to/my_script`.

Comment: John Anderson thank you that solved my problem