# PyInstaller: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 112: invalid start byte

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I was trying to convert my project to the exe with PyInstaller,
I tried the solution on this link with two options:
[Error when using pyinstaller: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47692960/error-when-using-pyinstaller-unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byt)

Also tried this solution, changed all **'utf-8'** encoding to the **'cp1252'**:
[UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x96 in position 35: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45529507/unicodedecodeerror-utf-8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x96-in-position-35-invalid)

But it could not solve my issue:

```
An error occurred while packaging
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\auto_py_to_exe\packaging.py", line 131, in package
        run_pyinstaller()
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
        run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
        PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in main
        build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 681, in build
        exec(code, spec_namespace)
      File "C:\Users\MFT\AppData\Local\Temp\tmplg5pykts\v7.spec", line 6, in <module>
        a = Analysis(['C:/Users/MFT/PycharmProjects/urunArayuz/v7.py'],
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 244, in __init__
        self.__postinit__()
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
        self.assemble()
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 422, in assemble
        self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 311, in process_post_graph_hooks
        module_hook.post_graph()
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 417, in post_graph
        self._load_hook_module()
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 383, in _load_hook_module
        self._hook_module = importlib_load_source(
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 797, in importlib_load_source
        return mod_loader.load_module()
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 462, in _check_name_wrapper
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 962, in load_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 787, in load_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 265, in _load_module_shim
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 702, in _load
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-zmq.py", line 20, in <module>
        hiddenimports = ['zmq.utils.garbage'] + collect_submodules('zmq.backend')
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 582, in collect_submodules
        names = exec_statement("""
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 85, in exec_statement
        return __exec_python_cmd(cmd)
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 74, in __exec_python_cmd
        txt = exec_python(*cmd, env=pp_env)
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 641, in exec_python
        return exec_command(*cmdargs, **kwargs)
      File "c:\users\mft\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 431, in exec_command
        out = out.decode(encoding, "replace")
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x87 in position 112: invalid start byte
```

Comment: That's strange. Could you please share you project files?

Comment: I suggest try different pyinstaller versions.

Comment: @NicholasObert it's 7779 lines are you sure about that? if u want i can upload in 5 min to external link on gdrive

Comment: mhh i guess that's not a great idea. Try different versions of pyinstaller, as @Sajad.sni suggested

Comment: At least its free and quick!!. As I can see in my python package manager there is an update for pyinstaller to version 4.0. maybe downgrade to previous versions fix the problem since there is not enough clue to figure it out. @NicholasObert

Comment: my last pyinstaller version 3.6 , I tried at that verseion and 4.0 also same issue

Comment: @FatihTüz follow along again with these links you provided with the version 4.0. I remember I faced with the same problem and solution in first link solved mine.

Answer (score 0):

It's interesting but, upgrading auto-py-to-exe solved my problem. I tried almost everything, but this basic solution was the one that made issue i guess...