# Error when using pyinstaller:UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 4055: invalid start byte

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, python-pptx

I have an issue when i compile a python code with pyinstaller.

The python code is using os, datetime, python-pptx, and tqdm packages.

When i use this line below for compile:

```
C:\test>pyinstaller -F Final_ver.py
```

I get this error message below: (Sorry for Long message)

```
301 INFO: PyInstaller: 5.11.0
301 INFO: Python: 3.11.3
322 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.19045-SP0
335 INFO: wrote C:\test\Final_ver.spec
338 INFO: UPX is not available.
340 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\test']
722 INFO: checking Analysis
722 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
723 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
725 INFO: Caching module graph hooks...
739 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
2575 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-heapq.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Jess\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
2849 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-encodings.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Jess\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
4226 INFO: Loading module hook 'hook-pickle.py' from 'C:\\Users\\Jess\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python311\\Lib\\site-packages\\PyInstaller\\hooks'...
5516 INFO: Caching module dependency graph...
5612 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
5615 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by C:\Users\Jess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe
5773 INFO: Analyzing C:\test\Final_ver.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\Jess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Jess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 194, in _console_script_run
    run()
  File "C:\Users\Jess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 180, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "C:\Users\Jess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 61, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Jess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 1006, in main
    build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
  File "C:\Users\Jess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 928, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\test\Final_ver.spec", line 7, in <module>
    a = Analysis(
        ^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 428, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "C:\Users\Jess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 184, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "C:\Users\Jess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 581, in assemble
    priority_scripts.append(self.graph.add_script(script))
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 268, in add_script
    self._top_script_node = super().add_script(pathname)
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Jess\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\lib\modulegraph\modulegraph.py", line 1419, in add_script
    contents = fp.read() + '\n'
               ^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb3 in position 4055: invalid start byte
```

I tried the solution mention in below but It's not worked.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47709800/18876363

change the line in the `Python\Lib\site-packages\Pyinstaller\compat.py`

`out = out.decode(encoding)`

to

`out = out.decode(encoding, errors='ignore')`

and also tried with

`out = out.decode(encoding, "replace")`

Just wonder Is there any other approaches for solving this issue?

Comment: Looks like one of your source files contains a badly encoded character (not UTF-8).

Comment: Also, you should try [Auto Py to EXE](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/), which provides a GUI interface for converting files to EXEs.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks for ur comments. I found out my source code was encoded by ascii; as i using visual studio and found out common encoding was ascii. just solved by 'save as' with encoding. A link below is what i used..!
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding?view=vs-2022

Comment: @BentheCoder Thanks for ur recommendation, I solved the utf-8 problem, but have an issue on creating pptx file with python-pptx. Seems like using pyinstaller with the python-pptx package have some issue. I'll try with Auto Py to EXE. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out my source code was encoded by ascii; as i using visual studio and found out common encoding was ascii. just solved by 'save as' with encoding. A link below is what i read on microscoft..!

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-save-and-open-files-with-encoding?view=vs-2022)

Comment: ASCII is valid UTF-8. And 0xb3 is not ASCII.